# regex patterns for seemingly simple task

Tags: c#, regex, string

Using C#

I need to create 8 regex patterns to check a bunch of arbitrary-length strings (one per line in a text file).  I'm trying to write the patterns as strings, then convert them to `Pattern` later.

The ones I believe I have:

1 . All numbers (eg 128329983928):     `"^[0-9]{string.length}$"`

2 . All lowercase (eg aejksanikp):     `"^[a-z]{string.length}$"`

3 . All uppercase (eg AIJDJWIHJMNQ):   `"^[A-Z]{string.length}$"`

The ones I need help with:

4 . All lowercase, all one letter (eg aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa)

5 . All uppercase, all one letter (eg AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA)

6 . Any case, one letter (eg AAaaaAaaAAAaAAaa)

7 . Any number plus any single letter, any case: (eg 1420A843aa830a3237A)

8 . Any single number (eg 22222222222222)

For numbers 4, 5, and 8, I could just do a bunch of | (or), but I was hoping there was a better way than `"a|b|c|d|e...{string.length}"`.  I really have no idea what to do for 6 and 7.

Comment: Head over: [http://regexpal.com/](http://regexpal.com/) and test around?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

4). This looks from the start (`^`) to end (`$`) of a string (or line, if `m` modifier).  It captures one alphabetical character (`([a-z])`), and then looks for that captured character 0+ times (`\1*`). [Demo](http://regex101.com/r/vK8qC6).

```
^([a-z])\1*$
```

5). Do the same thing, but initially capture the group `[A-Z]`. [Demo](http://regex101.com/r/eO1tL8)

6).  You can either use `[a-Z]`, `[A-z]`, `[a-zA-Z]`, or just use the `i` modifier to make it case insensitive.  [Demo](http://regex101.com/r/oL5pP1) (with modifier).

7). This one is a little more tricky.  We still use the anchors `^` and `$` like before.  But now we look for 0+ digits and capture an alphabetical character (this means the letter can come first or after some number of digits).  After this, we look for either a digit or the captured letter 0+ times until the end.  It sounds like a letter is **required**; however, if you want it to be optional, you can put a `?` after the captured letter (`([a-z])?`).  Remember to make this one case-insensitive with the `i` modifier or replace the capture group with `[a-zA-Z]`. [Demo](http://regex101.com/r/kK4eS1).

```
^\d*([a-z])(\d|\1)*$
```

8). Replace `[a-z]` in example 1 with either `[0-9]` or `\d`. [Demo](http://regex101.com/r/sB7iS9).

---

**References:**

- [Shorthand Character Classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) (i.e. `\d`)
- [Grouping and Capturing](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) (we used this to capture the character and reference it with `\1`)

---

**NOTE:** Since this seemed like homework, *please* ask if you have questions on how things worked beyond my explanations so you learn a thing or two about expressions :)

Comment: +1 You beat me in mentioning the importance of matching the 'whole string'.

Answer (score 1):

> 4 . All lowercase, all one letter (eg aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa)
>
> 5 . All uppercase, all one letter (eg AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA)

Since these two will be:

```
"^[a]{string.length}$"
"^[A]{string.length}$"
```

you should able able to determine the rest (Hint: [] represents a set)

**Edit:** Changed the patterns to cater for the fact the input is *"one per line in a text file"* and the regexp needs to match the whole line.

Comment: Much easier, get rid of the brackets and braces: `a+` and `A+`. And don't forget string begin/end: `^a+$` and `^A+$`. Otherwise, a string like "bbbAAAcsfdfsdf" would result in a match, too...

Comment: There is always more than one way to write any regexp and the ones provided above do perform the required match. So they work.

Comment: I'm saying the user needs to understand what the [] represent in a regexp.

Comment: Ah, okay, i was under the impression your statement referred to the whole of my comment. If you talk just about the brackets, then yes, i agree with you :-) But it still is not a solution for the given tasks *"All lowercase, all one letter"* and *"All uppercase, all one letter"* because of the missing '^' and '$' markers

Comment: Based on how the user posted the question I got the impression he/she did not really understand that [] represents a set. Now that may or may not be the case, but in my reply the only point I was trying to make was that the [] do represent a set and IMHO understand that fact is quite fundamental to understanding regexp.

Comment: No, i understand you, and i agree with what you say. But with respect to the question: The given tasks (which really looks like homework) are quite clear, and thus your answer is not an solution/answer to the question asked. I think the regexes given at the first three tasks detracted you from the verbal description of the tasks :) Now, just add those damn ^ and $ so i can remove my -1. Don't make me wait :-))

Comment: The only problem with *Now, just add those damn ^ and $* is those extra constructs now in the question, were not in the question when I posted my answer. Since my posting the question has been edited ;)

Comment: And yes, reading the "one per line in a text file" part of the question, I agree with you that using ^ and $ is the way to go ;)

Comment: Now just edit your answer. I want to revoke my -1 (given the comments here provide some relevant context to your answer), but i can't since it is locked (it is more than 20min ago since i set it), and revoking it now requires an edit to the answer... argh...

Answer (score 0):

1. ok
2. ok
3. ok
4. `^([a-z])\1{string.length-1}$`
5. `^([A-Z])\1{string.length-1}$`
6. `^(?i)([a-z])\1{string.length-1}$`
7. `^([a-zA-Z0-9]){string.length-1}$` unless it must start with a number then you'd go
   for: `^[0-9][a-zA-Z0-9]{string.length-1}$`
8. `^([0-9])\1{string.length-1}`

Note that:

- `^` means beginning of string and `$` end of string. This prevents
  partial matches.
- `(?i)` means the start of the case insensitive search.

Comment: I recommend using a regex tool and play with the variations. Here is one: http://regexhero.net/tester/ but there are many others.

Comment: Only note is that number 7 sounds like there can only be one letter (case-insensitive) (similar to 1 and 6 combined).